# How to transform the consecutive numbers into several class in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

For example, a number in `[0, 8]` should return `0`, in `(8, 16]` return `1`, in `(16, 24]` should return `2`, etc...

Then if I have a Tensor `[2,3,9,18]`, how can I get the output list `[0, 0, 1, 2]` in TensorFlow?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Now I use `tf.case` for this demand

```
c0 = lambda: tf.constant(0.)
c1 = lambda: tf.constant(1.)
c2 = lambda: tf.constant(2.)
c3 = lambda: tf.constant(3.)

cases = lambda x: {tf.less(x, 9.): c0, tf.less(x, 18.): c1, tf.less(x, 24.): c2}
condition = lambda x: tf.case(cases(x), default=c3, exclusive=False, name='condition')
output = tf.map_fn(lambda x: condition(x), input, name='prediction')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be solved in many different ways depending on how big the list of ranges are or if they follow a mathematical pattern. If it is a simple usecase, I will go with your solution slightly modified to be more clear.

(1)

```
def func(x):
    if x<=8:
        return 'A'
    elif 8 < x <= 16:
        return 'B'
    elif 16 < x <= 24:
        return 'C'
    else:
        return 'D'
```

If the ranges follow a mathematical pattern like in the example, you 
can do like below

(2)

```
classes = "0ABCD"
def clamp(num):
    return classes[ceil(num/8)] # TODo error checking
```

Or if there are a lot of ranges, then you can store sorted ranges in a list and do a binary search.
(3)

```
ranges = [(0,8,'A'),(8, 16, 'B'), ...]
#TODO use binary search from.. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html
```

Comment: Thk! I use the first method, and use `tf.map_fn`, I wonder is some `API` can do this. The second method is  good for this but in reality the region is not uniform and probably is `0,3,8,15,16`...